# Pull entire Java statement out of file using Bash

Tags: java, regex, bash, grep

I have several directories which contain large Java files and I would like to pull out all the log messages. This includes log.error, .info, etc. In general, they look something like this:

```
logger.error("some message here");
```

The problem is that some of these messages include line breaks, and therefore grep is not picking up the full message:

```
logger.debug("operation [" + j + "] = whatever " + ids[j] + 
" name: " + names[j] + " time: " + times[j]);
```

Is there a way that I can use regular expressions to get the entire Java statement, up to the semicolon?

Here is what I have so far:

```
grep -rn --include \*.java "\b\.error(\"\b" *
```

Comment: Is this for removing log calls from release builds? Or do you want to get the log lines for some other reason? If it's for removing the log calls, then use a tool like proguard which are designed to do that already.

Comment: There will always be cases that don't work. regular expressions are just not the right tool for programming language parsing.

Comment: I'm using it for analysis purposes. I'd like to make sure all the messages are consistent across different modules and different files. And I'm no regex pro, so I had no idea if there was some solution I was just overlooking. I figured it wouldn't be pretty though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -iname '*.java' -exec awk '/logger/,/;/' *.java +
```

As an example, let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file.java 
some(text);
logger.debug("operation [" + j + "] = whatever " + ids[j] + 
" name: " + names[j] + " time: " + times[j]);
other(text);
logger.error("some message here");
more(text);
```

Let's extract its logger statements:

```
$ find . -iname '*.java' -exec awk '/logger/,/;/' {} +
logger.debug("operation [" + j + "] = whatever " + ids[j] + 
" name: " + names[j] + " time: " + times[j]);
logger.error("some message here");
```

This works by looking for lines that contain `logger` and printing every line from there to the first line that contains `;`.

As Henry points out in the comments, regex algorithms like this are not foolproof.  But, if you are using this just for visual inspection, this should be a good start.

If you also want to record the file name and line number:

```
$ find . -iname '*.java' -exec awk '/logger/,/;/{printf "%s:%s: %s\n",FILENAME,FNR,$0}' {} +
./file.java:2: logger.debug("operation [" + j + "] = whatever " + ids[j] + 
./file.java:3: " name: " + names[j] + " time: " + times[j]);
./file.java:5: logger.error("some message here");
```